# Delimiters in split function Julia

Tags: string, split, julia

I got some issues trying to split a sentence in single substrings. Using the split function, I can't manage to use more than a delimiter. The code is:

```
sentence = "If you're visiting this page, you're likely here because you're searching for a random sentence"

split(sentence, "," , " " , ";")
```

I get this error:

```
LoadError: MethodError: no method matching split(::String, ::String, ::String, ::String).
```

I would like to get an array of single words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provide a vector of `Char`s as the `split` argument (in Julia quotation `"` is used for `String` and apostrophe `'` for `Char`):

```
julia> split(sentence,[' ',',',';'])
16-element Vector{SubString{String}}:
 "If"
 "you're"
 "visiting"
 "this"
 "page"
 ""
 "you're"
 "likely"
 "here"
 "because"
 "you're"
 "searching"
 "for"
 "a"
 "random"
 "sentence"
```

Comment: This is in the documentation for `split` (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.split).

Comment: Thank you. I tried your suggestion on VS Code and It gave me a method error. Instead, I tried it on Julia's REPL and It went fine. Is there a different syntax for script mode?

Comment: VSCode is sometimes not perfect on what it suggests